# weird behavior of raspberrypi.local: work well after reboot windows but after suspension stop functioning

Tags: ssh, windows, dns, ping

I'm very confused, it's been a week since I'm encountering this problem.
I can reach and connect to my raspberry from raspberrypi.local if I reboot or after shutting down and start again my computer but if I suspend, raspberrypi.local stops working. I can still continue to connect from IP.

I've installed avahi-daemon as other threads suggest and added to configuration `allow-interfaces=wlan0` to make sure that nothing like doker could possibly interfere.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c 1 raspberrypi.local
PING raspberrypi.local (192.168.1.117) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.117 (192.168.1.117): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.225 ms

--- raspberrypi.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.225/0.225/0.225/0.000 ms
```

To make things more confusing, I've tried to use all other computers that I can reach to try ping, and one never reaches the raspberrypi.local but works on its ip. The other seems to work always.
(for context: I'm always trying from windows 7 or 10 to raspberry)

Could be the firewall?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Seems strange to me 'cause should not work always or never

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

Other info that can be useful:
I'm using rasbian

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It's no just good just installing `avahi-daemon` you've also got to run it when the mDNS service stops responding.

Comment: @Dougie I'm not sure to understand correctly your comment, I've never use it before, but I'm pretty sure that avahi-daemon is running because systemctl status avahi-daemon says that is active, the ipv4 and ipv6 are registered and the host name is raspberrypi.local

Comment: The other thing is, probably, is not a raspberry side problem because on one pc is running properly. I just tried to disable windows defender (without other ideas I will try anything) on the one that is not working but no response the problem continue to persist

Comment: Run `sudo avahi-browse -d raspberrypi.local` to test whether avahi is responsive. That works on any Linux system. Windows should use mDNS by default (Win 10/Win 11).

Comment: WRT "is this a firewall?": https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything and it is unclear what effect this would have. The standard dhcpcd already supports the functionality.

Try a fresh installation.

Comment: I know but I encountered the same problem with the native network manager so I've tried something else

Comment: FYI: I've read recently that `dhcpcd` has been replaced by network manager (?) in the latest distro.